# Komodo couldn't find breakpoints outside of the main script

Tags: php, xdebug, komodo

I'm debugging php symfony2 project with komodo, everything is working when I put a breakpoint inside app_dev.php script, debugger stops right there when I'm running debug session. But when I put a breakpoint inside other file, which code is 100% running, Komodo just could not find it and runs to the end of my debug session. I'm keeping the file with the breakpoint opened for editing in Komodo IDE and don't know why it's happening, all is configured for debugging. I'm using Komodo IDE 9, Komodo 8.5 works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try removing your Mapped URIs from your preferences (Edit > Preferences > Mapped URIs) if there are any imported from 8.5.  If the paths don't match properly then Komodo can skip over your breakpoints.

The Komodo dev team monitors the Komodo forums if you want a quicker reply: http://forum.komodoide.com/